# How to use 8-bit UART to convert a data bus wider than 8-bit into serial?

Tags: uart, serial

From [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication?_ga=2.82358742.133139963.1644666977-1856347779.1644666977):

A UART IC is used for parallel-to-serial conversion. And it looks like below:

[image]

There are only 8-bits on the parallel side.

So what if the data bus is more than 8-bits?

Is there any wider UART?

Comment: "Serial" means different things. There are such things as 16-bit serial buses, a [74F676 does exactly that](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/74F676.pdf). Are you asking specifically about RS232 communications? You can always split things into 7 or 8 bit bytes if you want to keep to those types of standards.

Comment: Most micros will address 8 bit devices, so interfacing a 8 bit uart onto, say a 64bit micro is not an issue. the code takes care of the packing/unpacking of the bytes. You'll find many of the peripherals on a modern PC still use an 8 bit byte as the base unit of transfer - SATA, USB, I2C, ETHERNET.

Answer (score 1):

A single serial 'lane' with most common USARTs is capable
of eight bits plus parity, and  has two serial connections (one for  input, one for output).   The possibility exists of
paralleling more than one such lane (and the old EIA-232
standard prescribes the 25-position connector pinout
for two  lanes).  Usually, one would not take binary words across a serial link, because the standards (like ASCII)
are about sequences of 6, 7, or 8-bit bytes.  Clock schemes
for common serial ports are tolerant of timing inaccuracy,
and the pause between bytes allows the receiver to re-establish timing synchronization for each byte.

Computer-specific words are various; hardwares
support big-endian and/or  little-endian byte packing, and
multiple word lengths, so the short-burst byte size packets of 'serial' ports gave way to solutions, like Ethernet,
that have precision timing to allow long bursts (packets)
of variable sizes to be received.   There was little
interest in small UART chips after high-performance
USART hardware and Ethernet  became common.

It was always possible to make longer serial ports; the Macintosh Extended keyboard used a microprocessor-mediated serial scheme
to send sixteen-bit information to its host.

Comment: While IBM PC keyboard port uses serial comms, it does not relate to UARTs in any way. The keyboard interface contains a serial bit clock and reception is implemented with a simple shift register. And the transmissions are not fourteen bits.

Comment: @Justme Yep, you're right.   I was misremembering, it was the Apple ADB keyboard that sent the long (sixteen) bit stream.

Comment: ADB is a serial port among others, true, it just does not use an UART, as it uses a custom synchronous bit-serial transmission protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The UART has to be set to same line parameters to communicate with another device.

Depending on what the device is defines what you communicate with it.

If you need to communicate arbitrary binary data between two systems, your software must use a certain protocol to split the data and send it as multiple UART frames.

As an example, if you have a 32-bit value, the software should send it as four 8-bit bytes to the UART one at a time so it is transferred as four UART frames, assuming 8N1. If your line parameters are for example 7N1, then software must split the 32-bit value to five 7-bit bytes and send five UART frames.

Typically, UARTs have only up to 8 data bits in frames, but some microcontrollers with built-in UARTs can be switched to 9-bit data frames for some special use. The UART peripheral inside a microcontroller can be on a 8-bit or 32-bit bus and the bitness of the bus has very little if nothing to do with how data is transmitted on the UART line.